# Python if-else within loop not working (skips if)

Tags: python-2.7

```
def searcher():
    mun = raw_input("Enter name of city> ")
    pal = mun.replace(' ', '')
    state = raw_input("Enter State abbreviation> ")
    city = pal + state
    city = city.upper()
    for r in range(sheet.nrows):
        for c in range(sheet.ncols):
            cell = sheet.cell(r, c)
            if cell.value == city:
                loc = r
            else:
                print "not found"
    cell = sheet.cell(loc, 15)
```

Why does the last if-else skips the 'if' and then print `not found` infinitely?

Comment: Is it really printing infinitely? Or is `sheet.nrows` times `sheet.ncols` just a really really big number? Keep in mind that "not found" will be printed once for each cell whose value doesn't equal `city`. If you only want "not found" to be printed once ever, then it doesn't belong inside the loops.

Comment: It's skipping the `if` block because `cell.value != city`, presumably.

Comment: it is skipping the if block even if cell.value == city. And yes, I only want it to print "not found" once if and only if no cell == city

Comment: and yes, sheet.nrows times sheet.ncols is a pretty large number. about 200,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a state variable like `found`

```
# Start out False
found = False
for r in range(sheet.nrows):
    for c in range(sheet.ncols):
        cell = sheet.cell(r, c)
        if cell.value == city:
            loc = r
            found = True # set it to True if we find the value
# Now, the for loops are done.
if not found:
    print "not found"
```